# Is it right to switch rows after adding one row to another in row transformation ?

Tags: matrices, transformation

I wanted to find the rank of the matrix, I ended up in this matrix after doing some row transformations :

$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 4 & 1 & 4 \\
    0 & 0 & 3 & 2 \\ 
    0 & 3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Is it right to switch any two rows now, i.e R2 <-> R3 so they become upper triangular and I get rank 3 ? Or should the switching of rows be done before doing addition of rows?

Comment: I would say that the order doesn't matter - I mean, yes you can switch the rows.

Comment: Switching rows preserves the rank at whatever moment you do it.

Comment: Thank you @Matti P and G. Sassatelli. I had a misconception that switching of rows should be done only in the beginning.

Comment: Gauss algorithm has you consider a switch of rows exactly $n$ times (one for each column) at prescribed moments. Namely, it's organised as "consider switching -> eliminate -> consider switching -> eliminate -> ..."